# When user created in table 1, copy username and id over to table 2

Tags: c#, sql, linq

You get created in UserAcc, and i want to transfer UserID and UserName over to Login table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE UserAcc (
    UserID INT NOT NULL,
    UserName VARCHAR(100),
    LastName VARCHAR(100),
    FirstName VARCHAR(100),
    Email VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (UserID)
);

CREATE TABLE Login (
    UserName VARCHAR(100),
    PassW VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (UserName),
    UserID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES UserAcc(UserID)
);
```

Is there a way in sql or can u do it in c#?

I have tried this in c# but it failes alot

```cs
var connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-VFKRIT8;Initial Catalog=DatingApp;User ID=sqlconn;Password=12345";
string query = "INSERT INTO UserAcc(UserID, UserName, LastName, FirstName, Email) VALUES (@UserID, @UserName, @LastName, @FirstName, @Email);" + 
                "INSERT INTO Login(UserID, UserName) VALUES (@UserID, @UserName);";
SqlConnection cnn;

// ID();
    IDte();

try
{
    cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn); 

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", userid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", usernamebox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", fnamebox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lnamebox.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailbox.Text);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Du er nu oprettet");
    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "transfer"?  That is not a basic SQL operation.

Comment: Also, this looks scarily like you're intending on storing password in plaintext. Please don't ever do that

Comment: I do store password as plaintext, but this is only a school project to learn sql/c# :))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT` as in:

```
insert into login (UserId, UserName)
    select UserId, UserName
    from UserAcc;
```